# Installing shp2pgsql-gui on Mac OSX Snow Leopard?

Tags: postgis, installation

I am getting started with PostGIS. I am trying to understand how to install the plugin shp2pgsql-gui under Mac. Right now my 'Plugins' tab in pgAdminIII is blank.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to just [install](http://opengeo.org/technology/suite/download/) the [OpenGeo Suite](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/usermanual/installation/mac/index.html). It comes with PostGIS and GeoServer. The PGAdmin included there already has the shp2pgsql-gui. No need to install anything else.